# Run Python Script from VBA - iwshshell3 error

Tags: python, vba, runtime

I'm trying to run a python script from VBA, but I'm getting run time error - IwshShell3 failed.
Code below:

```
Sub RunPython()
Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExec, PythonScript As String

Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

PythonExec = """C:\Users\123\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.7.exe"""
PythonScript = "C:\Users\123\Projects\Run.py"

objShell.Run PythonExec & PythonScript

End Sub
```

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a space between those two parts:

```
objShell.Run PythonExec & " " & PythonScript
```

Answer (score 0):

step 1 install python idle
https://www.python.org/downloads/

step 2 install windows PowerShell to convert .py file to .exe file
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/install/installing-windows-powershell?view=powershell-7.2

step 3 win + r, after that input cmd

step 4 cd C:\Users\ATM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310 (Note - ATM is my user name)

step 5 py -m pip install pyinstaller (this is very important to install, in order to convert .py files to .exe files)

step 6 py -m pip install pandas

step 7 same way install all the python libraries that you need after that you can close command prompt.

step 8 open windows PowerShell, use below command in it. (Note - ATM is my user name and in place of filename below, your python file name will come that needs to be converted to .exe)

step 9 C:\Users\ATM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts> .\pyinstaller --onefile -w 'filename.py'

step 10 go to -> C:\Users\ATM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\dist

step 11 for more details to convert to exe file https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-python-script-to-exe-file/

step 12 copy paste the exe file where you need it to be and open VBA use the below code

```
Dim objShell As Object

PythonScriptPath = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\FILENAME.exe"

RetVal = Shell(PythonScriptPath, 1)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
```